# Export Google Chart to Excel Sheet in Angular

Tags: angularjs, excel, export, google-visualization

Im using ng-google-chart to create charts from data I receive from a database. I store the data in a table. I need to export both the table and the chart.

I'm using the following technique to export tables (where "exportable" is the div the contains the table):

```
 $scope.export = function () 
{

 var blob = new Blob([document.getElementById('exportable').innerHTML], {
                type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;charset=utf-8"
            });
            saveAs(blob, "Record.xls");


            alert("export done"); 
        };
```

I cannot find any way to add the chart to this file.

This is the code to generate a chart

```
var chart1 = {};
                    chart1.type = "ColumnChart";
                    chart1.cssStyle = "height:400px; width:500px;";
                    chart1.data = {
                        "cols": [
                            { id: "gender", label: "Gender", type: "string" },
                            { id: "number", label: "number", type: "number" }

                        ], "rows": [
                            {
                                c: [
                                   { v: "male" },
                                   { v: $scope.male, f: $scope.male }

                                ]
                            },

                            {
                                c: [
                                   { v: "female" },
                                   { v: $scope.female }

                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    };

                    chart1.options = {
                        "title": "",
                        "isStacked": "true",
                        "fill": 20,
                        "displayExactValues": true,
                        "vAxis": {
                            "title": "Number", "gridlines": { "count": 6 }
                        },
                        "hAxis": {
                            "title": "gender"
                        }
                    };

                    chart1.formatters = {};

                    $scope.chart = chart1;


                }
```

Comment: what about [getImageURI](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/printing) to create an image of the chart?

Comment: Is there a way I can add the image to the excel file when it is created?

Comment: not sure, maybe try replacing the actual chart with the image, then it will get downloaded from the `innerHTML`...?

Comment: Can I get the URI of the chart? That way I could include it in the table and it could be exported

Answer (score 0):

To [getImageURI](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/printing) of the chart, wait for the `ready` event and call the function.
Then you can add the image somewhere on the page.
You can even hide the original chart if needed...
Following is an example of loading the image URI into another element.

```js
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages:['corechart'], callback: drawChart});

function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ["Element", "Density", { role: "style" } ],
    ["Copper", 8.94, "#b87333"],
    ["Silver", 10.49, "silver"],
    ["Gold", 19.30, "gold"],
    ["Platinum", 21.45, "color: #e5e4e2"]
  ]);

  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
  view.setColumns([0, 1,
                   { calc: "stringify",
                     sourceColumn: 1,
                     type: "string",
                     role: "annotation" },
                   2]);

  var options = {
    title: "Density of Precious Metals, in g/cm^3",
    width: 600,
    height: 400,
    bar: {groupWidth: "95%"},
    legend: { position: "none" },
  };
  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById("chart_div"));

  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
      document.getElementById("chart_image").insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', '<img alt="Chart Image" src="' + chart.getImageURI() + '">');
  });

  chart.draw(view, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<span>CHART</span>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
<br/>
<span>IMAGE</span>
<div id="chart_image"></div>
```

Comment: how can I export the image as a png? or jpg?

Comment: the URI should be saved as PNG

Comment: when i include in img in the table and give it an src of some image on the internet, the image gets exported. But if i give it the uri of the graph (or any downloaded image), instead of the image, i get a box in excel which says "The linked image cannot be displayed. The file may have been moved, renamed or deleted. Verify that the link points to the correct file location".

Any ideas. I'd appreciate any help

Comment: @IsmaeelAfaqi Is this issue fixed?

Comment: issue still exists, download img with url, no problem -- if src = uri, doesn't download -- work around is to save uri as png then provide url to png -- [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40028701/5090771) uses sharepoint web service to save the img to png...