# Export Google Chart to Excel

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, charts, google-visualization, office365

There is a requirement to export Google charts as such into Excel. Is there way to achieve the same through jquery? From the Google Chart documentation, I understand the chart can be converted to an image by getting ImageURI. But when tried to export the image using ImageURI (please refer link-2) its is not loaded in the excel file.

Reference:

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/printing

```
$("[id$=myButtonControlID]").click(function(e) {
    window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent( $('div[id$=divTableDataHolder]').html()));
    e.preventDefault();
});

<button id="myButtonControlID">Export Table data into Excel</button>
<div id="divTableDataHolder">
    <title>Demo for huge data</title>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="5">
                    Demoe By <a href="http://codePattern.net/blog">CodePattern.net</a>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

            <tr>
                <td>Anil Kumar</td>
                <td>2012</td>
                <td>Delhi</td>
                <td>India</td>
                <td><img src='data:image/png;base64,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' alt=''/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>abc</td>
                <td>12</td>
                <td>Delhi</td>
                <td>India</td>
                <td>Earth</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>abc</td>
                <td>12</td>
                <td>Delhi</td>
                <td>India</td>
                <td>Earth</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>abc</td>
                <td>12</td>
                <td>Delhi</td>
                <td>India</td>
                <td>Earth</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>abc</td>
                <td>12</td>
                <td>Delhi</td>
                <td>India</td>
                <td>Earth</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>abc</td>
                <td>12</td>
                <td>Delhi</td>
                <td>India</td>
                <td>Earth</td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qt32a/86/

Comment: @WhiteHat I have the image URI instead of URL. Is it possible to insert image to excel using image URI.

Comment: @WhiteHat If I provide the image URL its displayed in the excel. but with URI its not

Comment: @WhiteHat If you use http://jsfiddle.net/qt32a/ and trying to export to excel in google chrome I can see the image is exported in excel but the with the URL in http://jsfiddle.net/qt32a/86/ its not exported to excel. Also regarding your question how to save the byte and use url, can you please explain.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125615/discussion-between-user2773448-and-whitehat).

Comment: @WhiteHat Thanks for your feedback, but how do I save URI to a file and also I cannot to my server and hence I don't think a proper URL can be given. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @WhiteHat Yes, I am using Office365 for development. The page is developed using html and jquery and I have added the same as web-part (Content and Media webpart).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since downloading the URI doesn't seem to work

save the URI to a file by uploading the base64 string to a sharepoint library

using the `CopyIntoItems` web service

when complete, or before download, replace the chart with the image

then when downloaded to Excel, the chart image should appear

see following snippet...

```
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['File', 'fileSize', 'output Target'],
      ['a', 10, 15],
      ['b', 12, 18],
      ['c', 14, 21],
      ['d', 16, 24]
    ]);

    var container = document.getElementById('chart_div');
    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(container);

    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
      var soapEnv = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>';
      soapEnv += '<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">';
      soapEnv += '<soap:Body>';
      soapEnv += '<CopyIntoItems xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">';
      soapEnv += '<SourceUrl>null</SourceUrl>';
      soapEnv += '<DestinationUrls><string>http://domain' + _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl + '/Temp/test.png</string></DestinationUrls>';
      soapEnv += '<Fields><FieldInformation Type="File" /></Fields>';
      soapEnv += '<Stream>' + chart.getImageURI().replace('data:image/png;base64,', '') + '</Stream>';
      soapEnv += '</CopyIntoItems>';
      soapEnv += '</soap:Body>';
      soapEnv += '</soap:Envelope>';

      $.ajax({
          url: 'http://domain' + _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl + '/_vti_bin/Copy.asmx',
          beforeSend: function(xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader('SOAPAction', 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/CopyIntoItems');
          },
          type: 'POST',
          dataType: 'xml',
          data: soapEnv,
          complete: function (result, status) {
            if (status === 'success') {
              document.getElementById('chart_div').innerHTML = '<img alt="Chart" src="http://domain' + _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl + '/Temp/test.png">';
            }
          },
          contentType: 'text/xml; charset="utf-8"'
      });
    });

    chart.draw(data, {
      legend: {
        position: 'bottom'
      }
    });
  },
  packages: ['corechart']
});
```

Comment: Thank you. I will integrate with my code and will update the status. First question where will the image be stored in sharepoint. Will this make any impact as there can n times the reports can viewed by user and also I have such 10 charts.

Comment: i created a document library called `Temp`, used in the code above -- this is where the image gets saved -- the library will continue to grow as more files are created -- still don't understand why URI won't work

Comment: Here is what I tried, inside td of a table i gave img src as URL and in another td i gave img src as URI and then I exported to excel. In the excel first td had image and second one didn't. Please note the URI value is used as img src. Is that not the right way to do.

Comment: One more question based on your code will the column type created in document library Temp be just multi line text. Also if I give the sharepoint Url of file in temp document library to export to excel, will the image be displayed in excel even in offline mode or even aftr the file is deleted from document library.

Comment: as for URI, it is correct as img src -- as for document library, it's not a list, so no fields to create, same as uploading a file. as for offline, not sure if excel saves the image or the address...? if address, need to keep images as long as excel file exists, and it wouldn't work offline -- not a great solution...

Comment: Your code worked for me. Thanks a lot, but there are issues which thought of i.e in the offline mode images cannot be viewed and also when ever user opens up the excel file it will ask for credentials for authentication.

Comment: cheers! glad to help, if you ever get uri to work, let us know!

Comment: Sure. I had post the query in Google Chart Forum. Incase I get any proper comments from them I will update it here